# Does upcasting ensure the preservation of a child's field in java?

Tags: java, casting

I'm going to use Hibernate for a persist some entities.

```
EntityClass entity = new EntityClass();
Object obj = (Object) entity;
hibernateSession.persist(obj)
```

Can I ensure that the field value in the original EntityClass will be preserved?

Does the garbage collector not clear field values?

In all other cases, can I ensure that the upcasting preserves the value of the original field?

(other common cases that don't use hibernate)

It is my original code

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(~~~); // from external file
Iterator<?> iterator = ((Iterator<?>) clazz.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(~~~); // from external file

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    for (JsonEntity content : (List<JsonEntity>) iterator.next()) {
        session.saveOrUpdate(content.toEntity());
    }
    session.flush();
}
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you don't need to cast and pass to entity object.

```
EntityClass entity = new EntityClass();
hibernateSession.persist(entity);
```

- as long as your entity class is being referred, will it not be garbage collection
- casting your object to a super class will not delete the original fields/methods but you can only access fields/methods which are available in super class only

Comment: The code written in the body is just a rough code for asking questions. 
anyway, answer was helpful. thx!

Answer (score 0):

upcasting a reference type (such as Entity) does not alter the object or it's fields. You can read more here : https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-casting

Neither does it require you to explicitly cast it since the compiler implicitly recognizes that Entity is a subclass of Object. You can simply do:

```
Object obj = entity;
```